# MYSQL SELECT statements

Tags: mysql

I made a table and I want to select certain data from the table using select statements.
I want to see all the book titles that  were published in May.
How can I go about doing this?

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE titles
  (
  title_id   CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  title_name VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
  type       VARCHAR(10)          ,
  pub_id     CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  pages      INTEGER              ,
  price      DECIMAL(5,2)         ,
  sales      INTEGER              ,
  pubdate    DATE                 ,
  contract   SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_titles PRIMARY KEY (title_id)
  )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM titles
    WHERE pubdate LIKE '%%%%-05-%%';
```

It displays the whole column, how can I get it to only display the books title?

Comment: `SELECT title_name FROM ...`

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I knew it was something simple. @GiorgosBetsos

Comment: You also don't need to use that many wild cards for LIKE.  It doesn't require you to put one in for every character that could possibly be there.  Just use one on each side of the -05- (ex. LIKE '%-05-%';)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT title_name FROM titles WHERE MONTH(pubdate) = '5'
```